# Reflection vs reference - IoC container registering

Tags: c#, reflection

I have some IoC container (it doesn't matter which one, but lets assume it is Autofac). In my solution I have more than 30 services which need to be registered. All services resides in the same assembly called **Services** and each class has a name in format **{specific_name}Service.cs**.

I'd like to avoid for some reasons registering each service manually this way:

```
container.Register<OneService>().AsSelf();
container.Register<TwoService>().AsSelf();
...
container.Register<ThirtyFourService>().AsSelf();
```

And register my types in this way:

```
Type[] serviceTypes = Assembly.Load("Services")
                      .GetTypes()
                      .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
                      .ToList();

foreach(Type serviceType in serviceTypes)
{
    container.Register(serviceType).AsSelf();
}
```

All I want achive is minimalistic registration process which allows me add or remove services and keep source code clean. Initialization of my application can be slow (server side application), but when first request comes, it has to behave as quick as possible (performance does really matter at serving responses). Saying initialization I mean registering types, reading configuration files, etc.

Does such reflection usage slow my application "at runtime" or just impact app initialization? How dependencies will be resolved later?

Comment: If its only run once, it only affects the initialization. Personally I'd avoid the types ending in "service" because what if somebody names it different? Create a custom attribute like `AutoRegisterServiceAttribute` and then add the attribute to the service types, and then get the types that have that attribute.

Comment: Yes, this is great idea. I'm using such approach, but I wanted to keep question as simple as possible :) The root of question is information, how reflection affects lifecycle of application.

Comment: Aside from loading the assembly, I've used a technique where all of my "Services" inherit an interface..example:  `this.Bind(syntax => syntax
                .FromThisAssembly() 
                .SelectAllClasses()
                .InheritedFrom<IGenericService>()
                .BindDefaultInterface()
                .Configure(config => config.InRequestScope()));`

Comment: @MarkC. - thanks for answer :) Again, I just wanted to ask a question as simple as possible :)

Comment: Are you trying to register concrete classes, or interface-to-class mappings? Because, in `Unity`, you *never* need to register concrete classes, only mappings. Concrete classes are "automagically" taken care of.

Comment: Both. Mostly these are interface to class mapping but some of them are self classes.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you do registration once there will be no impact on requests - both ways of registering (`.Register<TwoService>().AsSelf()` and essentially `.Register(typeof(TwoService)).AsSelf()`) should do exactly the same thing. You can check yourself for container of your choice that one simply calls another.

Note that depending on container you use there could be existing way to register "all types matching pattern". I.e. Unity already "registers" all types - so there in no need for `Register<ConcreteType>()` at all.

Answer (score 0):

In AutoFac, there are two ways to control the lifetime of your request: **InstancePerHttpRequest** or **InstancePerApiRequest**.

But, If you use InstancePerHttpRequest or InstancePerApiRequest it will be basically the same thing, you will need to parser for all Services of your class and register them. I don't think that it will be to more expensive for your application, because some extensions are doing the same thing. E.g. AutoFac like AutoFac for MVC 5 or Autofac for web Api.

So, if you are not concerned about few milliseconds of performance, you can go for it.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine it is still using Activator.CreateInstance for each of the services, so there is a minor hit there, as well as the obvious reflection discovery service. I don't think you have anything to worry about performance wise from the container perspective. If for some reason you do run into issues, check another container for better performance as this is a common use case and should be supported quite well and widely.